AcroForms PDF form on the web
I am currently trying to display a PDF form as part of my web page (not like described here: Embed a fillable pdf form on web page, they are using Acrobat for this). The user should be able to edit the PDF form fields (I only care about AcroForms right now) like he would in a PDF viewer (fill in the text boxes, check the radio boxes, etc.). The PDF viewer included in Firefox and Chrome can do this, and as I understand it the one in Firefox uses pdf.js for that. I've tried to use PDF.js for this, too but I cannot find any good documentation on how to render the text and form part (See my question here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/discussions/19183). Also, the react-pdf module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) does not have any documentation for PDF forms. How do I achieve this?
The code I have came up with so far is (see link above, I am also using Mantine, but I do not think this is relevant for the question):
import { Button, Center, Flex, Input, Paper, Text } from "@mantine/core";
import * as pdfjslib from "pdfjs-dist";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { IconAt } from '@tabler/icons-react';
import $ from "jquery";

pdfjslib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
    'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.mjs',
    import.meta.url,
).toString();

async function renderCanvasLayer(pdfPage: pdfjslib.PDFPageProxy
    , canvas: HTMLCanvasElement
    , viewport: pdfjslib.PageViewport) {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")!;

    const renderTask = pdfPage.render({
        canvasContext: ctx,
        viewport,
    });

    return await renderTask.promise;
}


async function renderTextLayer(pdfPage: pdfjslib.PDFPageProxy
    , div: HTMLDivElement
    , canvas: HTMLCanvasElement
    , viewport: pdfjslib.PageViewport) {
    $(div.id)
        .css({
            left: canvas.offsetLeft + 'px',
            top: canvas.offsetTop + 'px',
            height: canvas.height + 'px',
            width: canvas.width + 'px'
        })
        .html("");

    const textLayer = new pdfjslib.TextLayer({
        textContentSource: await pdfPage.getTextContent(),
        container: div,
        viewport: viewport
    });

    return await textLayer.render();
}

async function loadPDFPage(pdfDocument: pdfjslib.PDFDocumentProxy
    , canvas: HTMLCanvasElement
    , div: HTMLDivElement
    , pageNum: number) {
    const pdfPage: pdfjslib.PDFPageProxy = await pdfDocument.getPage(pageNum);

    const viewport = pdfPage.getViewport({
        scale: 1.5
    });

    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    canvas.height = viewport.height;

    await renderCanvasLayer(pdfPage, canvas, viewport);
    await renderTextLayer(pdfPage, div, canvas, viewport);
};

function Page({ numPage, pdfDocument }: { numPage: number, pdfDocument: pdfjslib.PDFDocumentProxy }) {
    console.assert(numPage != null);
    const pageCanvas = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
    const pageDiv = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (pageCanvas.current && pageDiv.current) {
            loadPDFPage(pdfDocument, pageCanvas.current, pageDiv.current, numPage);
        }
    }, [pageCanvas]);

    return <>
        <Paper
            shadow="xl"
            p="xl">
            <Center>
                <Flex
                    mt={10}
                    mih={10}
                    gap="sm"
                    justify="center"
                    align="center"
                    direction="column"
                    wrap="wrap">

                    <canvas ref={pageCanvas}></canvas>

                    <div ref={pageDiv} className="select-text"></div>
                    <Text>Seite {numPage}</Text>
                </Flex>
            </Center>
        </Paper >
    </>
}

function PageArea({ numPages, pdfDocument }: { numPages: number, pdfDocument: pdfjslib.PDFDocumentProxy }) {
    const pages = [];

    for (let i = 1; i != numPages; i++) {
        pages.push(<Page numPage={i} pdfDocument={pdfDocument}></Page>);
    }

    return <>
        {pages}
    </>;
}

But I am also open for solutions using approaches other than PDF.js, as long as they work in the browser.
Thanks!
Edit: I updatated the title after some research on my own, this question is about Acroform PDFs, I do not care that much about XFA, it is obsolete anyway.

Please do not provide links alone. Instead add a text-based [mre] to the question

okay, will update

I would recommend not mixing jQuery and React. React doesn't do well when sharing with other libraries.

Try by passing fqdn for workerSrc.
because im displaying pdf file by using same library in nextJs [compnent is same as react]

@VarunDeva And does that work with PDF forms?

PDF "readers" are editors that can edit the contents of files FROM the WWW after download. The methods were developed last century by a company bought out by Adobe and rebadged as AcroForms since designed for Acrobat Pro / Reader.
Modern clones like PDF.js are well developed to use such contents and add extra data such as highlights, inking and text entries.
Here is a current Mozilla rendering as images and HTML text, before saving the overlaid information back into the source downloaded PDF.

So every online PDF reader is an offline editor of the served data. At the top of that tree is Acrobat Reader which can "talk" via backchannel to a collaborative server. Thus in fact "report/watch" (via data export) what a user is doing. Acrobat is mandatory for some Adobe proprietary contents (usually "National" forms), as the internal reader functions cannot be used without a licensed server.
However most others are simply clients slaves. Hence may refuse to follow any servers monitoring / instructions.
This web forms viewer can add text, but there is no JavaScript EVER allowed in its functions. The PDF was posted "inline" by the server thus dis-positioned as clients application/pdf for their edits.

To Write AcroForms, you need a PDF generator. This can be a simple text editor or a very complex JavaScript Editor and one perhaps most suited to the task between the two is PDF-LIB.js.
see www. jsfiddle.net/Hopding/bct7vngL/4/


Thank for for your answer. I want to present the User with an existing AcroForms PDF that he can fill out while staying on my page, not allow him to edit it. I nevertheless appreciate your input and have further clarified the question. Many thanks for your time looking into this!
